# Projecting from Irish Transverse Mercator (ITM) to WGS84 latitude-longitude

Tags: python, geopandas, pyproj

Unfortunately my projection from Irish Transverse Mercator (ITM) to WGS84 latitude-longitude seems to have gone wrong as the plotted coordinates don't line up with a map of Dublin [sourced from the CSO](https://data.gov.ie/dataset/local-electoral-areas-osi-national-statutory-boundaries) (see below).

[My transformed coordinates plotted on a map of Dublin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeALx.png)

The transformed data was sourced from the [Irish Valuation Office](https://api.valoff.ie/) and the ITM X & Y coordinates were fed into a function adapted from a [previous stackoverflow discussion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32418/python-script-to-convert-lat-long-to-itm-irish-transverse-mercator) which uses geopandas' built-in **points_from_xy** method to transform coordinates between Coordinate Reference Systems:

```
def create_geodf_from_GPS (df, latitude, longitude, crs):

    locations = gpd.points_from_xy(longitude, latitude)
    geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=locations)
    geo_df.crs = crs

    return geo_df


VO_geo = create_geodf_from_GPS(VO, VO[" X ITM"], VO[" Y ITM"], crs = 'epsg:2157')
VO_geo = VO_geo.to_crs('epsg:4326')
```

Does anyone have any idea what may have gone wrong here?

Comment: You have latitude and longitude switched: the function takes latitude first, but you pass X first

Comment: Unbelievable!  That does the trick!  Thanks @joris

Comment: (Unfortunately my SO reputation is too low to upvote your comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple fix thanks to @joris

Altered function using x & y as arguments for gpd.points_from_xy instead of the previously mixed up longitude & latitude:

```
def create_geodf_from_GPS (df, x, y, crs):

   locations = gpd.points_from_xy(x, y)
   geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=locations)
   geo_df.crs = crs

return geo_df
```

Now plotting the data in WGS84 latitude-longitude works as expected:

```
VO_geo = create_geodf_from_GPS(VO, x=VO[" X ITM"], y=VO[" Y ITM"], crs = 'epsg:2157')
VO_geo.to_crs('epsg:4326').plot()
```

**Note**: the data had to be cleaned to remove obvious outliers by filtering out non-Dublin data using geopandas' (gpd) spatial join function

```
VO_geo_clean = gpd.sjoin(VO_geo.to_crs('epsg:4326'), map_of_Dublin)
```

**Result:**
[VO data plotted over a map of Dublin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nblTo.png)